# Thunderbolt on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - GC-Titan Ridge PCIE card

Tags: thunderbolt, gigabyte

I have a GC-titan ridge card v1, installed and configured on my Lenovo Thinkstation P720. It is working fine in windows 10.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get it working on my Ubuntu installation. Tried it with few thunderbolt devices - Raid and USB-C drives and none are recognized.

The closest I have to see something is by using tbtadm where I get:

```
Controller 0
    └─ Details:
        ├─ Name: GC-TITAN RIDGE, GIGABYTE
        └─ Security level: SL1 (user)

I guess it is recognizing the card, but none of the devices attached to it.

If I run lspci -tv I also get the following:

 +-[0000:85]-+-00.0-[86-8b]--+-[0000:8b]---00.0  Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
 |           |               +-[0000:89]---00.0  Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
 |           |               +-[0000:87]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
 |           |               |           +-01.0  Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
 |           |               |           +-02.0  Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
 |           |               |           \-04.0  Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
 |           |               \-[0000:86]---00.0-[00]--
```

Can anyone help me? Alternatively, I could also invest on a new PCIE card if I could only find one that is compatible with Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: did you ever figure this out?